# What layout object is used to produce a "bubble" popup in an Android UI? (Not Toast or Dialog)

Tags: android, user-interface

I've looked through the developer.android.com and googled quite a bit, but I can't seem to find a layout object that does this: A speech bubble sort of thing that has within it a list of buttons, which may be scrollable if not all of the buttons fit within the screen width. The Twitter app, Handcent SMS, and HTC's Sense messaging app all use this, and it looks more or less the same in all of them, which is what makes me think it's a standard object. The pic below is from Handcent. What are they using?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what's often referred to as the [QuickActions UI pattern](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html). There is no direct support for this out-of-the-box in the Android SDK, but there are several examples out there you can use.

One of them, which I've used myself is [How to Create QuickAction Dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/). If you look at that link, you'll get a good explanation of how it is done, and you can even download the source code and use it directly in your own app.

Comment: Fantastic! Clearly I couldn't find it because the name is not obvious and it is not supported. Thank you.