# What is this Android Widget called?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm sorry for such a silly question, but I can not fathom the name of this component and no amount of googling is yielding results. It's like a dialog window in a chat that holds views. I *believe* it's a standard UI component (possible in a later version of android).

[image]

Comment: This may be what you're looking for, but I'm not positive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482865/what-layout-object-is-used-to-produce-a-bubble-popup-in-an-android-ui-not-toa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its nothing but the  Quick Action Dialog ..

Check this for the [Quick Action Dialog Widget](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)....

Comment: How can I add that to the search screen? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502330/how-to-add-a-drop-down-next-to-the-search-input-field-in-android

Comment: ? Where do I hook that into the standard search manager? Cusomizing the Quick Action Dialog is the 2nd step then :)  Thanks  Heiko

Answer (score 2):

That is a custom component specific to the search app.

The only API which is similar would be the [QuickContact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.QuickContact.html) class. It provides a similar contextual popup for actions related to a contact (e.g., call, SMS, email, etc.).

You can use third-party libraries such as [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) for similar functionality.

[GreenDroid popup example http://lh4.ggpht.com/_OHO4y8YcQbs/TQFQZTft6OI/AAAAAAAAMpY/hAloaii6kRA/s800/gd7.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_OHO4y8YcQbs/TQFQZTft6OI/AAAAAAAAMpY/hAloaii6kRA/s800/gd7.png)

Answer (score 0):

On my HTC (with sense, android 2.2) I can get it by adding it trough

longclick -> widget -> 'google search' -> choosing 'all'