# Can any one point me which widget is this?

Tags: android

PFA screenshot

The widget below symbol 'G' with three options "All", "Web", "Apps"..Whats the name of the widget?.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568445/what-is-this-android-widget-called) which says it is the Quick Action Dialog.