# What is this Android component called?

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, android-layout

Google uses a very neat activity/view slider in many of their apps. I'm wondering if you know what it is called? If it is  available in any of the open sources apps? Or if you have an idea how to build one?

It works as a tabbed pane showing just the current, the previous and the next tab. Swiping left or right on the pane, or in the activity, moves you between the views with a lovely, coordinated animation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this Android Widget called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568445/what-is-this-android-widget-called)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what it's officially called. However pakerfeldt has made an open source version called viewflow which is available on github: 
https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

Comment: I found a description here: http://pakerfeldt.com/horizontal-view-flow-with-android/ I won't need the Adapter concept though, but I'll have a good look at the source. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After further research I found out they are called [Workspaces](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/06/android-ui-pattern-workspaces.html).
They are used in the Google IO 2011 Schedule app, where the code is available.

**Update:** [Google has now released a standardized implementation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).